# Definite integration weird problem

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

If $$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^2dx}{(x^2+a^2)+(x^2+b^2)+(x^2+c^2)}=\frac{\pi}{2(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)}$$, then what will be the value of $$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{dx}{(x^2+4)(x^2+9)}$$

Comment: I'm just working on removing them

Comment: Partial fractions will work fine here, just as a note.

Comment: Uhm could you proceed a bit further?

Comment: Could I? Yes. Will I? No, unless you add some context to your post to make it match the [site guidlines](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). Where did you get this problem? What have you tried?

Comment: My instinct would be to do this with partial fractions $\frac 15 \int \frac 1{(x^2 + 4)} - \frac 1{(x^2 + 9)} dx$  then you have two  arctan functions.

Comment: The first identity cannot hold. The LHS is a function of $a^2+b^2+c^2$ only, while the RHS is not.

Comment: Moreover, the integral in the left hand side is not even converging, since the integrand function tends to $\frac{1}{3}$ for large values of $x$.

Comment: Well, aren't the both expressions different since there is a term of $x^2$ in the numerator of given expression while its not there in numerator of asked expression ?

Comment: @Zlatan: I don't get what you are stating, I am simply claiming that the first identity is wrong. It cannot hold, for multiple reasons.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming $a,b>0$ we have that
$$ \frac{1}{(x^2+a^2)(x^2+b^2)}=\frac{1}{b^2-a^2}\left(\frac{1}{x^2+a^2}-\frac{1}{x^2+b^2}\right) \tag{1}$$
and:
$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{dx}{(x^2+a^2)(x^2+b^2)}=\frac{\pi}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{b^2-a^2}\left(\frac{1}{a}-\frac{1}{b}\right) = \frac{\pi}{2ab(a+b)}.\tag{2}$$
By multiplying both sides of $(1)$ by $\frac{x^2}{x^2+c^2}$ and performing the same decomposition twice we have that the correct identity is, for $a,b,c>0$,
$$ \frac{\pi}{2(a+b)(a+c)(b+c)}=\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{x^2\,dx}{(x^2+a^2)\color{red}{\cdot}(x^2+b^2)\color{red}{\cdot}(x^2+c^2)}.\tag{3}$$
We may recover $(2)$ from $(3)$ just by setting $c=0$.

Comment: I do not see the problem with $a,b<0$, at least for the first parts, where the squaring should remove any signs.

Comment: @SimpleArt: you are right, actually there is a sign issue just when we say $$\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{dx}{x^2+a^2}=\frac{\pi}{2a}.$$ In order to avoid it, one may assume $a,b,c>0$ or replace $a,b,c$ with $|a|,|b|,|c|$ in the RHS of $(2)$ and the LHS of $(3)$. Just a matter of taste.

Comment: Hi !!!. The original post is a sum in the denominator ( $\color{#f00}{\Large +}$ instead of $\color{#f00}{\Large .}$ ). Maybe it's an OP misprint.